Is there a way to mix grabpass and RimLight?
I started creating a shader that ideally mixes grabpass and rimLight, I learned about multipass, but I don't know how to use them in surface shaders, can someone help or explain it to me?
I searched online and i found a guy that write the pass after the endcg, I tried to do the same in my shader, just writing the rimlight pass after the grab pass, but it doesn't worked

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
